# IIS IP Restrictions and Start/End Ranges

Tags: iis, ip, range, mask, restrictions

Preface:  I have only a basic understanding of IP address; not a network guy.

I have a list of IP start and end ranges in the format of XXX.XXX.XXX.0 to XXX.XXX.XXX.251.

I need to manually enter these ranges into the IP restrictions feature of IIS Manager to allow or block them - IIS Manager is asking for "A range of IP addresses:" and the "Mask:".

How do I determine which values to enter into IIS IP restrictions.

I have tried using various online IP range calculators but I honestly don't trust them all with my limited knowledge of IP addresses, and we can't afford to shut down possibly multiple sites due to an error.

Comment: Hi! You have to know what IPs you have to block.. Can you explain better what are you trying to do?

Comment: Hopefully...I know which IPs to block.  As an example, the start and end range for one entry is 76.210.74.48 to 76.210.74.63 (not an actual IP range).  We want to allow this fictitious range into our website with deny set for anything else.  The IIS Manager "Add Allow Restriction Rule" dialog has two options: (1) Specific IP Address, or (2) A range of IP addresses, including a mask.  I don't know enough about how to determine the correct format and the mask; and I don't have anyone here to ask.

Comment: Ok can you post some screenshot?

Comment: However 76.210.74.32 network with 255.255.255.224 describe all IPs from 76.210.74.32 to 76.210.74.63 excluding 76.210.74.32 (Network ID) and 76.210.74.63 (Broadcast address)

Comment: The IP addresses...I wish I could, they are a bit "sensitive".

Comment: You can test it in another environment, install IIS on a PC, forward ports on home router and try it at home

Comment: How do you calculate the "255.255.255.224" value?  This is what I need.  Believe me, I am scouring the Internetz to find out.